# tagging the column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id        Month       Year        processed      success
A          Jan        2021             0           0
A          Feb        2021             0           1
A          Mar        2021             1           0
B          Jan        2021             0           1
B          Feb        2021             0           0
B          Mar        2021             0           0
B          Apr        2021             0           0
C          Dec        2021             0           0
C          Jan        2022             0           0
C          Feb        2022             1           0
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
  Id            final_status
  A             Paid
  B             UnPaid
  C             Paid
```

I am trying to create a Tag as Paid and UnPaid for the Id. Condition for **UnPaid** is to check for the last three consecutive month if either success or Processed doen't have any count it is to be flagged as "Unpaid"  else "Paid"

stuck with applying conditions.

Comment: Yesterday solution not working for you?

Comment: need to check in both the column Processed and success. also just for last three months

Comment: need this flag for different context

Answer (score 1):

First create helper `Series` for test if not `1` in both columns by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = (df[['processed','success']].ne(1).all(axis=1)
        .groupby(df['Id']).agg(lambda x: np.where(x[-3:].all(), 'UnPaid', 'Paid'))
        .reset_index(name='final_status')
        )
print (df1)
  Id final_status
0  A         Paid
1  B       UnPaid
2  C         Paid
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[['processed','success']].ne(1).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last 3 rows per group, and check whether there is at least one 1 in the whole slice.

For this use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), in which the last 3 rows/values are selected with [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html), compared to 1 with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and finally check if there is at least one occurrence with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html).

One option:

```
N = 3
(df.groupby('Id')
   .apply(lambda d: d.tail(N).eq(1).any(axis=1).any())
   .map({True: 'Paid', False: 'UnPaid'})
   .reset_index(name='final_status')
)
```

Or:

```
N = 3
(df[['processed', 'success']]
 .eq(1).any(axis=1)
 .groupby(df['Id']).apply(lambda s: s.tail(N).any())
 .map({True: 'Paid', False: 'UnPaid'})
 .reset_index(name='final_status')
)
```

Another with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
N = 3
(df.groupby('Id')
   .apply(lambda d: np.where(d.eq(1).to_numpy()[-N:].any(), 'Paid', 'UnPaid'))
   .reset_index(name='final_status')
)
```

Output:

```
  Id final_status
0  A         Paid
1  B       UnPaid
2  C         Paid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    idxmin1=dd.query("processed==0 and success==0").index.min()
    return "UnPaid" if dd.loc[idxmin1:].pipe(len)>=3 else "Paid"

col1=((df1.processed.add(df1.success))>0).cumsum()
df1.groupby(['Id',col1]).apply(function1).rename("final_status").groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
  Id final_status
0  A         Paid
1  B       UnPaid
2  C         Paid
```